# Logstash : geopip from json

Tags: json, logstash, geoip, kibana-4, logstash-grok

I am trying to geolocate the requests on my rails application. I have configured Lograge to generate my logs in json.

I think logstash is not able to retrieve the remote_ip from the json and process the geoip.

Here is the decoded json with the empty geoip field in Kibana :

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2016.03.15",
  "_type": "rails logs",
  "_id": "AVN6t1-FkghE9kQv20fc",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2016-03-15T14:39:10.176Z",
    "client": {
      "host": "www.myapp.com",
      "remote_ip": "\"xx.xx.xx.xxx\"",
      "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36",
      "browser": "Chrome",
      "browser_version": "48.0.2564.116",
      "plateform": "windows"
    },
    "geoip": {}
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1458052750176
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1458052750176
  ]
}
```

Here is my logstash.conf

```
input {
  file {
    type => "rails logs"
    # * is for indexing rotated logs
    path => "/var/www/myapp/shared/log/production.log*"
  }
}
filter {
   grok {
       match => [
          "message",
          "%{DATA:data}%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} -- : %{GREEDYDATA:json}({({[^}]+},?\s*)*})?\s*$(?<stacktrace>(?m:.*))?"
       ]
       remove_field => ["message"]
   }
   json {
       source => "json"
       remove_field => ["json"]
   }
   geoip {
      source => "[client][remote_ip]"
      target => "geoip"
      database => "/etc/logstash/GeoLiteCity.dat"
      add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
      add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}"  ]
   }
   mutate {
      convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float"]
   }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
    }
}
```

Did I miss something in my configuration ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like "remote_ip" is not correctly parsed, it has double quotes.
I guess the geoip filter does not work because it does not manage remote_ip as an ip.